# Custom options in <FontSelector in React-chart-editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly

How can I give custom options in FontSelector component, every time i give custom font options, It is overwritten by its three default Font options.
My component

```
<FontSelector label="Typeface" 
   options={[ { label: 'Open Sans', value: '"Open Sans"' }, 
            { label: 'verdana', value: 'verdana' }, 
            { label: 'sans-serif', value: 'sans-serif' }, 
            { label: 'New-Font', value: 'Helvetica Neue' } ]} 
   value="sans-serif" 
   attr="textfont.family" />
```

But i get different options in dropdown

[image]

Comment: please include some code to understand what approach you are using

Comment: I'm giving my own fonts as dropdown options in Fontselector as given in code above. but it rendering the different options in dropdown as shown in image

Answer (score 0):

NB: Options passed should be array of objects.
Try this below code, it can help you.

```
<FontSelector label="Typeface" 
   options=[{"label": "Open Sans","value": "Open San"},
        {"label": "verdana","value":"verdana"},
        {"label": "sans-serif","value": "sans-serif"},
        {"label": "New-Font","value":"Helvetica Neue"}]
   value="sans-serif" 
   attr="textfont.family" />
```

Comment: I have given options as array of objects, that extra curly braces is for jsx so that it can understand it as a javascript expression